# Failed to retrieve Session from FacesContext inside a Servlet Filter

Tags: jsf, session, servlet-filters, facescontext

After autheticating my user, I want to put a reference in the session to current logged in user.

Here how I do it in the `setCurrentUser` method :

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("CURRENT_USER", currentUser);
```

Unfortunately, the `session` reference is always null !

Alternatively, I tried with the sessionMap

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Map<String, Object> sessionMap = facesContext.getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
sessionMap.put("CURRENT_USER", currentUser);
```

It miserably failed with this exception :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractMap.put(AbstractMap.java:186)
    (...)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

The full code of my controller

**UserController.java**

```
public class UserController implements Filter {
    private FilterConfig fc;
    private static final String CURRENT_USER = "CURRENT_USER";

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        fc = filterConfig;
        log(">> Filter initialized");
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Authenticate user
        // ...

        // Save refernce in Session
        setCurrentUser(currentUser);

        //(...)
    }

    public static void setCurrentUser(User u) {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute(CURRENT_USER, u);// session is always NULL
    }

    public static User getCurrentUser() {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(true);       
        return (User)session.getAttribute(CURRENT_USER);
    }

    //...   
}
```

**JSF 2.0**
**JBoss 5.1.0.GA**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `FacesContext` is not available in a `Filter` as the `Filter` is invoked *before* the `FacesServlet`.

You should be getting the session from the `request` argument instead.

```
HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession();
session.setAttribute("user", currentUser);
// ...
```

Once you're in JSF context (e.g. inside a JSF managed bean or a JSF view), then this will be available by `getSessionMap()` on the very same attribute name

```
User user = (User) externalContext.getSessionMap().get("user");
```

Or just by `#{user}` in EL:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{user}")
private User user;
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I did:

```
public class SesionUtil implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void setSesionUsuario(String key, Object value) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put(key, value);
    }

    public String getSesionUsuario(String key) {
        return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get(key).toString();
    }
}
```

And then, to initialize the session, I simply executed:

```
@Inject // Inject dependency
private SesionUtil sessionUtil;

...

sessionUtil.setSesionUsuario("nombreUsuario",nombre);
```